# Polymer Starter Kit did not go to mobile layout in production

Tags: mobile, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I am trying to start developing my personal web using polymer starter kit as my basis. When I tried to run the web locally using python server, it all ran well and the mobile mode is working. But when I upload it into my Github, it does not change into mobile layout if I open it in my Android phone.

Any idea why?

My full code is available at:
https://github.com/flamechamp/flamechamp.github.io

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? What do you mean by open it in the phone? Also, please try to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), rather than just pointing to a external link with a couple of files.

Comment: Hi, I tried opening it both using Chrome in my Nexus 6P and the developer tools in desktop Chrome to emulate phone. In both cases, the polymer starter kit sample entered mobile mode while my site does not enter mobile mode.

If only I know which part of the code is processing this mobile compatibility, I would not be so troubled. But it is all supposed to be standard polymer starter kit codes which is available: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit